# bootstrap-wysiwyg not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I am trying to provide bootstrap-wysiwyg editor. It works fine in firefox but in IE I am getting exception

```
Unhandled exception at line 30, column 7 in http://localhost:21585/Scripts/plugins/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js

0x80040100 - JavaScript runtime error: This command is not supported.
```

The line is

```
if (document.queryCommandState(command)) {
```

command = "fontSize 5"

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Since IE can't handle "fontSize 5" you have to remove the "5".

So locate the following lines in **bootstrap-wysiwyg.js**

```
var command = $(this).data(options.commandRole);
if (document.queryCommandState(command)) {
```

and change it to look like this

```
var command = $(this).data(options.commandRole);
command = command.split(' ').shift();
if (document.queryCommandState(command)) {
```

Answer (score 4):

I resolve this issue as below:
find:

```
$(options.toolbarSelector).find(toolbarBtnSelector).each(function () {
                    var command = $(this).data(options.commandRole);
                    if (document.queryCommandState(command)) {
```

change this line:

```
if (document.queryCommandState(command))
```

to:

```
if (editor.is(':focus') && document.queryCommandState(command))
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests, "fontSize 5" is not a valid command name. Use "fontSize" instead.

References:

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [MDN (Mozilla)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands)

Comment: Well, command is also "fontSize 5" in firefox and in firefox everything is working fine.

Comment: @RaoEhsan: Doesn't change anything. Firefox may be doing some forgiving error checking.